# Docker pull for nanoserver / windowsservercore failing with message failed to register layer access is denied exactly at the end of extract

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am using the below link to pull docker image

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10

Step 3 to pull nanoserver image error occurred. This is also happening for windowservercore image pull as well. Error shown as

Exactly at the end of extract it is failing with access is denied. Below errors from event viewer

Error trying v2 registry: failed to register layer: rename C:\ProgramData\docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\tmp\write-set-552404215 C:\ProgramData\docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\sha256\342d4e407550c52261edd20cd901b5ce438f0b1e940336de3978210612365063: Access is denied.

Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: failed to register layer: rename C:\ProgramData\docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\tmp\write-set-552404215 C:\ProgramData\docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\sha256\342d4e407550c52261edd20cd901b5ce438f0b1e940336de3978210612365063: Access is denied.

UPDATE 1: The issue happening on a few microsoft/* images not all the images.

Comment: There were couple of existing question in SO on this and it results image failure while pulling from repository for `microsoft/nanoserver`, at least from couple of posts. Are you running as administrator?

Comment: yes running as admin in the powershell console.

Comment: this scripts checks a lot of prerequisites: test it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/live/windows-server-container-tools/Debug-ContainerHost/Debug-ContainerHost.ps1

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it seams to be something wrong with accessing the image.

An issue is open with docker hub.

[Unable to pull docker images of  microsoft/nanoserver or](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/874)